# How to end a program using blank line in python?

Tags: python, blank-line

```
fee = []

age = int(input("Enter age: "))

while age != '':

    age = int(input("Enter age: "))

    if age <= 5:
        fee.append(0)
    elif age >= 6 and age <= 64:
        fee.append(50.00)
    else:
        fee.append(25.00)

total = sum(fee)
print("Total payment: ", total)
```

I want to make a program that would sum up the given entrance fees. I don't even know if I'm doing it correctly

Comment: After the first input operation, `age` is an integer. You are then comparing that integer to an empty string. When would you expect the two to be the same? BTW, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your are not even asking a question. Also, if not even you known if you're "doing it correctly", how could anyone else? What exactly is *your* definition of "correctly" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a string to an integer, that's your main problem. If you retrieve it from the user as a string and check it is indeed an integer or not will work. That code should do the trick:

```
def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

fee = []

r='start'

while r != '':

    r = input("Enter age: ")
    if RepresentsInt(r):
        age = int(r)
        if age <= 5:
            fee.append(0)
        elif age >= 6 and age <= 64:
            fee.append(50.00)
        else:
            fee.append(25.00)

total = sum(fee)
print("Total payment: ", total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fee = 0

age = int(input("Enter age: "))

while age != '':
    try:
        age = int(input("Enter age: "))  // to avoid exception of string
    except:
        break
    if age <= 5:
        fee += 0  // no need to append if outcome is a number
    elif age >= 6 and age <= 64:
        fee += 50
    else:
        fee += 25

total = fee
print("Total payment: ", total)
```